# Unable to import org.junit.Assert.AssertThat;

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, import

I am unable to `import org.junit.Assert.AssertThat` in my program. I am using Ganymede and jUnit 4.8.1.

Answer (score 21):

### Static Imports

It's [`org.junit.Assert.assertThat(T, Matcher<T>)`](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat%28T%2C%20org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) and you can import it as a static import:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat
```

now in your client code you can do `assertThat(something, ismatched())`

**Reference:** [Java Tutorial > The Static Import Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html#staticimport)

---

### Regular Imports

To do it the old-school way, if you import the `Assert` class like this

```
import org.junit.Assert
```

you can call it using `Assert.assertThat(something, isMatched())`

(The `isMatched()` method is something that you'd have to implement)

---

### assertThat()

`assertThat()` was first described [in this blog post](http://joe.truemesh.com/blog/000511.html) and has been part of JUnit [ever since version 4.4](http://junit.sourceforge.net/README.html), so make sure you have **JUnit version 4.4 or newer** on the classpath. Also, make sure that your compiler compliance level is 1.5 or higher:

[image: Set Eclipse compiler compliance level]

Answer (score 3):

The method is called `assertThat` (lower a, capital T). And if you import it like that you need to use a static import:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
```

But since you don't tell us the error message I can't really tell if that will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "i am using ganymede" you are stating that you are using the "ganymede version of eclipse", do the following:

1. Open the project properties.
2. Click on "Java Build Path".
3. Select the Libraries tab.
4. Click the "Add Library" button.
5. Choose junit.

You should now be able to import junit classes into your project.

Comment: *Assuming that by "i am using ganymede"* The [alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganymede) don't sound likely :-)